# 'functionInBackboneView' is not a function - context in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view where I set `droppable` to an element. I want to access the '*outer*' `addOperator` method but how? It gives an error saying it is not a function.

```
var CanvasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#canvas",
    render: function () {
        $("#canvas-container").droppable({
            drop: this.handleDropEvent
        });
    },
    addOuterOdperator: function (toolID) {
        console.log(toolID);
        console.log("outer");
    },
    handleDropEvent: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("inside handle func");
        var id = 0;
        var addInnerOperator=function(ie){
            console.log("inner");
        };
        addInnerOperator(id);
        //this.addOuterOperator(id); gives an errror 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting error with `this.addOuterOperator` because you are within event handler context. So to avoid that you may try below code:

```
var CanvasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#canvas",
    render: function () {
        var self = this; //creating a self reference
        $("#canvas-container").droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                self.handleDropEvent(event, ui, self); //passing the self reference
            }
        });
    },
    addOuterOdperator: function (toolID) {
        console.log(toolID);
        console.log("outer");
    },
    handleDropEvent: function (event, ui, selfRef) {
        console.log("inside handle func");
        var id = 0;
        var addInnerOperator=function(ie){
            console.log("inner");
        };
        addInnerOperator(id);
        selfRef.addOuterOperator(id); //accessing the function via selfRef
    }
});
```